# Is ArcGIS 10.1 Desktop compatible with 10.0 Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

Since upgrading my "ArcGIS for Desktop" (Windows 7) client to 10.1, I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out how to publish a Map Service on my (CentOS) 10.0 Server. Back on 10.0 Desktop, I would just load up my .mxd, use the Map Service Publishing toolbar to make a .msd, and then FTP the .msd with the data (it's contained in a file geodatabase) to the server and start a new map service in Server Manager. Easy!

Now the "Map Service Publishing" tool has changed into a completely different "Publishing" tool. If I skip the .msd and try to publish just the .mxd with the FGDB, the <s>map is blank</s> server says the format of the MXD is invalid.

I can't be the only one in this situation, but I don't see any Desktop<->Server compatibility information on 10.0 and 10.1. I don't know if I'm just doing something wrong or the two products really aren't compatible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can publish on "ArcGIS Server 10.0" MXD files generated by "ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1", but I have to use the menu "File"->"Save a copy"->"ArcMap 10.0 Document".

By other hand, using the same "ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1", I made some MSD files via ArcPython, but I got an error when trying to publish this MSD on "ArcGIS Server 10.0".

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I think Victor may be on the right track with the "save as 10.0" approach. Could you copy the 10.0 MXD to the server, then use ArcGIS Server Manager (rather than ArcCatalog 10.1) on the 10.0 server to publish the service directly from the MXD?

Comment: This works so I'll set this as the correct answer, thanks! It's just strange that there seems to be no way to create a 10.0 compatible MSD file in 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

I was using 10.1 to publish to a 10.0 server (Windows Server 2008 .NET) for a few weeks with no issues.  I will say, 10.1 makes it **very** easy to publish from external sources not connected to the ArcGIS server in any way. By default in 10.1 Server, if the ArcGIS server cannot access the Map Document and layer files then the data will be copied to the ArcGIS Server when the service is published.

Comment: Do you remember how you were publishing to the 10.0 server? You can't just "Share as a Service" like you can with a 10.1 server, because the old server doesn't know what to do with the new .sd file you're sending it. (I can't even make a connection to the 10.0 server)